# PHP Как найти все ссылки с пустым или отсутствующим href атрибутом?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как убедиться что в теге а присутсвует атрибут `href` и что он не пуст,
и задать корректное значение ?.

Как это реализовать без `DOMDocument` ? Потому Что после сохранения у меня летят кодировки.Ну в общем пока что не хочу связываться с ним.

Пытаюсь это сделать следующим образом но у меня ничего не выходит

```
    $html = <<<HTML
       <a href='' title='title1'>AAA</a>
       <a class='xyz' href='' title='title2'>BBB</a>
       <a title='title1'>CCC</a>
       <a class='xyz' title='title2'>DDD</a>
HTML;
    $html = preg_replace_callback(
        '/<a(.*?)(href=)?([\'"][\'"])?(.*?)>/',
        function ($matches)
        {
            return "<a{$matches[1]}href='aaa/bbb'$matches[3]>";
        },
        $html
    );
 echo $html;
```

Помогите пожалуйста.

Спасибо.

Comment: не по сабжу,  но в качестве коммента, вместо `preg_replace_callback` в данном случае можно пользовать просто `preg_replace`, где в замене на соответствия ссылаться вместо `$matches[1]` просто `$1`

Comment: Используйте DOMDocument + DOMXPath. XPath - `//a[not(@href and string-length(@href) > 0)]`. А потом `.setAttribute("href", $val)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew мне нужна именно регулярка ,без DOMDocument. Я поправил вопрос

Comment: Нужно использовать DOMDocument. Лучше бы задали вопрос, почему летят кодировки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дабы вопрос не остался без ответа, предложу одно из решений с помощью регулярных выражений. Используется два шаблона.
 Первый шаблон `#<a(.+)href=(\'|\")\\2(.+?)>#` отбирает ссылки с пустым атрибутом `href`. При этом могут использоваться как одинарные так и двойные кавычки `(\'|\")`, с помощью обратной ссылки `\\2` проверяется, что закрывающая кавычка совпадает с открывающей. В шаблоне замены с помощью групп `$1` и `$3` подставляются все исходные атрибуты ссылки.

Второй шаблон с помощью `SKIP & FAIL` *(о которых, кстати говоря, я прочитал на ruSO пару дней назад)* пропускает все ссылки, у которых атрибут `href` заполнен: `#<a.+href=(\'|\")[\w/]+\\1.*?>(*SKIP)(*F)|<a(.+)>#"`, таким образом оставляя нам только ссылки, где  атрибут отсутствует.

```
foreach(explode("\n", $html) as $h){
    $result = preg_replace([
                 "#<a(.+)href=(\'|\")\\2(.+?)>#",
                 "#<a.+href=(\'|\")[\w/]+\\1.*?>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|<a(.+)>#",.
               ],
               ["<a href='first'$1$3>", "<a href='second'$2>"], $h);
}
```

На выходе имеем следующий результат (`0` - исходная, `1` - результат):

```
Array(
    [0] => <a href='' title='title1'>Одинарная, пустая</a>
    [1] => <a href='first'  title='title1'>Одинарная, пустая</a>
)
Array(
    [0] => <a class='xyz' href='' title='title2'>Пустая, одинарная в середине</a>
    [1] => <a href='first' class='xyz'  title='title2'>Пустая, одинарная в середине</a>
)
Array(
    [0] => <a title='title1'>Нет</a>
    [1] => <a href='second' title='title1'>Нет</a>
)
Array(
    [0] => <a class='xyz' title='title2'>Нет</a>
    [1] => <a href='second' class='xyz' title='title2'>Нет</a>
)
Array(
    [0] => <a class="xyz" title="title2" href="/test">Двойная, ссылка</a>
    [1] => <a class="xyz" title="title2" href="/test">Двойная, ссылка</a>
)
Array(
    [0] => <a class="xyz" title="title2" href='/test'>Одинарная, ссылка</a>
    [1] => <a class="xyz" title="title2" href='/test'>Одинарная, ссылка</a>
)
Array(
    [0] => <a href="qeqweqwe" class="test">Двойная, ссылка</a>
    [1] => <a href="qeqweqwe" class="test">Двойная, ссылка</a>
)
```

Первое правило меняет атрибут на `first`, второе на `second`